# Modprobe could not insert module; exports duplicate symbol

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel-modules

I have built an [Linux From Scratch](http://linuxfromscratch.org/) system on my laptop, but am struggling to get my Elan Touchpad working. I have narrowed down the search to an issue with the module `i2c_designware_core` not being loaded.

I am trying to load the module `i2c_designware_core`, but get an error:

```
$ modprobe i2c_designware_core
[  197.551934] i2c_designware_core: exports duplicate symbol i2c_dw_probe (owned by kernel)
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'i2c_designware_core': Exec format error
```

Searching in the Linux kernel source code yields that the symbol `i2c_dw_probe` is only found in the i2c_designware-related directories. Running `rmmod i2c_designware_core` tells me that the module is not loaded.

The kernel compilation configuration is set to compile i2c_designware-software as modules, and I have recompiled and reinstalled several times already.

How can the symbol be exported by the kernel if it only exists in a module I have made sure not to build into it?

Comment: If the kernel is one you built yourself, and the module is part of it, I'd restart the make after a "make -clean".

Comment: I have made sure to use `make mrproper` between each build, as recommended by the Linux From Scratch web site.

Comment: And you've installed kernel and modules and rebooted?

Comment: I have run `make modules_install` after `make` and in the end copied the correct bzImage and System.map files to a boot folder, where it is loaded by  grub. - And also rebooted, yes.

Comment: You should have used "make install", not copy yoursalf.

Comment: You are probably right, I followed the instructions given at LFS and failed to modify them correctly, my mistake anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I had made a terrible mistake when installing the kernel, causing GRUB to load an older one. I guess it makes sense that the duplication happened when trying to load the external module at the same time as the module was built-in.

Sorry for the trouble.

Comment: The world is stil turning.